# Unable to add the Angular.js Script in Plunker editor

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**VERY SIMPLE PROBLEM**

I'm new to Angular and trying to learn it with use of Plunker Editor.

I try to add the resource Angular.js but I get an error while adding the script.

```
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.31" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular.js"></script>
```

I get this error in console.

> POST
>   http://api.plnkr.co/catalogue/packages/angular.js/bump?sessid=56309ecdefb522120023d1e2
>   404 (Not Found)
>   h @ xdomain.min.js:3g @ xdomain.min.js:3j.send @
>   xdomain.min.js:3(anonymous function) @ xdomain.min.js:3d @
>   xdomain.min.js:3c.(anonymous function) @ xdomain.min.js:3(anonymous
>   function) @ xdomain.min.js:3

Can anyone help me fix this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Second icon, right of the page.

Comment: I did the same way. I pulled it from Resources Tab.

Comment: Using the Plunker editor seems to always fill the console with various errors. I wouldn't worry about it unless it actually effects the running of **your code**

Comment: Definately it is throwing 404 Error in console and the Angular is not in the control of my page and all the bind variables are appearing as text instead the values because Angular is not able to take control of my HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. It was happening as I was not logged in to plunker using GitHub. I logged in to GitHub and gave access to plunker and it started working.. 
Anyone trying to use plunker please login via GitHub to get its complete benefit.

Comment: How does github login is related to addding angluarjs script ?

Answer (score 0):

As @sailens suggests use the Plunker UI to add it.  You don't need to add it directly in your code.  Here's a bare bones include.  Start there.

http://plnkr.co/edit/SDlQMocWuBJYSZyBj8Ce?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.31" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I did the same way. I pulled it from Resources Tab.

Comment: I do not see resources tab. Maybe they have changed. I cannot find way to import angularjs. When I run other examples it looks like it is working. Or when I start fresh project I can choose angularjs. But cannot find way to add angular to existing project.

Comment: Looking at the site, you now need to do an include directly in the source.  It used to be that you would add it via a resource tab, however, the time has passed and the site has changed.